# How to use learning rate continuously in caffe?

Tags: caffe, hdf5

How can I use learning rate continuously when I train large amount of the training data in caffe?

I am trying regression program and I want to use more than 200k images. I could not find the way to use lmdb because lmdb can not specify floating points, and I also could not find the way to use large size of hdf5 files more than memory.

So I devided the hdf5 files, then I trained each files in order by using fine-tuning. However, learning rate is always inialized by this way because iteration becomes zero when I call caffe at each time. The result is overfitting and I think this is one of the reason.

Does anyone know the way to use learing rate continuously?

Comment: what do you mean by "could not find the way to use large size of hdf5 files more than memory"? you can split your data into several hdf5 binary files and provide `"HDF5Data"` layer with a *txt* file listing all the binary files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I thought we could use only one hdf5 file per each training. You are right. I misunderstood,  but thanks anyway.